# Custom Component, display function is not called from specific view/controller

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have made a custom component, also with help from component-creator.com. But I am struggling with display methods. For example I want to check something in the display method, but when I try to add that the display method isn't even called. it seems that it only calls from the base controller.

I don't understand why it works like this.

rootcomponent/controller.php

```
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

use \Joomla\CMS\Factory;

/**
 * Class MatchesController
 *
 * @since  1.6
 */
class MatchesController extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController
{
    /**
     * Method to display a view.
     *
     * @param   boolean $cachable  If true, the view output will be cached
     * @param   mixed   $urlparams An array of safe url parameters and their variable types, for valid values see {@link JFilterInput::clean()}.
     *
     * @return  JController   This object to support chaining.
     *
     * @since    1.5
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
    {
        
        $app  = Factory::getApplication();
        $view = $app->input->getCmd('view', 'matches');
        $app->input->set('view', $view);

        $user = Factory::getUser();

        if ($user->get('guest') == 1) {
            $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=' . base64_encode(JUri::current()), "You must be logged in to view this content"));
            return;
        }

        parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

rootcomponent/controller/matches.php

```
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController;

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * Matches list controller class.
 *
 * @since  1.6
 */
class MatchesControllerMatches extends BaseController
{
    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
    {
        echo "See if display function is called here";
        die();

    }

    /**
     * Proxy for getModel.
     *
     * @param   string  $name    The model name. Optional.
     * @param   string  $prefix  The class prefix. Optional
     * @param   array   $config  Configuration array for model. Optional
     *
     * @return object   The model
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    public function &getModel($name = 'Matches', $prefix = 'MatchesModel', $config = array())
    {
        $model = parent::getModel($name, $prefix, array('ignore_request' => true));

        return $model;
    }

}
```

rootcomponent/matches.php

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use \Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController;

// // Include dependancies
// // jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

JLoader::registerPrefix('Matches', JPATH_COMPONENT);
JLoader::register('MatchesController', JPATH_COMPONENT . '/controller.php');


// Execute the task.
$controller = BaseController::getInstance('Matches');
$controller->execute(Factory::getApplication()->input->get('task'));
$controller->redirect();
```

I don't know if you need more code?

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: @Lodder i have added some extra code

Comment: @HuubS - if you call the display method with `…&task=matches.display` it should call the `display()` method of that controller. Does it not?

Comment: According to my tests, if you call the method of that subcontroller explicitely in URL, the controller is going to be called and it will respond with the method, but this is not your fault here that Joomla does not call the display() of that subcontroller as default, it is Joomla’s illogic and that is why I wrote what I wrote earlier on this. You rightfully expect that display() method of that subcontroller is going to be called even if you just call the controller only. Instead of that, Joomla automatically calls the View display() function (if it is not there, then the `default` tmpl file is

Comment: called (in `matches` View folder).

Comment: So, if you just use the controller name as `task=matches` Joomla does not even care if there is a subcontroller there under that name. The BaseController automatically looks for the View with that name. However, if you call `task=matches.display`, Joomla will use that subcontroller and that method. Do not try to find logic in that. With that said, you can handle the guest redirect in `matches.php` root file even before the main controller is called, with an `if (task == ‘matches’)` condition using `$app->input->get(‘task’)` using factory to call app. And then redirect in that root file.

Comment: @Zollie Thank you for your reply. I find that logic indeed very illogical. You should expect that it checks if the subcontroller has that function. The reason I asked is because I set a menu item for the Matches view. And thus it does not specify the task. So your advice is to just move all the logic to the display of the root file controller?

Comment: As a test I created `profiles` controller and also in views folder a `profiles` view and layout (earlier based on your question). This is where I want the registered user to be arrived when task profiles is called.  Then either you can redirect in matches.php in root or you can also create a `profiles()` method in the base controller of your component and you can redirect in that method, since Joomla will understand that `task` that way.

Comment: Ok thank you. I begin to understand. What i dont understand right now though is how Joomla specifies the links for the menu items. When I make a menu item for the Matches view it doesn't use the task, it uses the component and the view name. That is the origin of my problem. Should I use custom urls for that, how would I tackle that?

Comment: Good question. You can check router.php files in components, but the fastest, easiest is as you wrote too with using a custom url menu.